# Is planting a Peepal tree a remedy for "afterlife tarpaṇa" rituals, in case a couple doesn't have a male progeny?

Tags: scripture, rituals, death, sraddha, peepal-tree

Recently on a *dhārmika* TV channel, I heard a *pundit* talk on the importance of the Peepal tree.

What caught my attention was when the *pundit* proclaimed that -

> " Planting a Peepal tree as a remedy for the "afterlife tarpaṇa" rituals, in case a couple doesn't have a male progeny, to perform those requisite "śrāddha" rituals. "

He further told that -

> " As long as the tree will live, so does the oblations automatically reaches the ancestors, even if no male progeny performs the annaual "śrāddha" rituals", etc..

So my question seeks the scriptural validity of this claim.